# Fail sending some data inside onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why I can't send a value to another function inside my `onClick`.

I have this,

```
function centerMapInfo(data){
    console.log(data);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    console.log('START');
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        ....
        centerMapInfo(data[i])
        $("#"+id_list).append("<li class='"+li_class+" list-group-item-warning font-weight-bold'><a href='#' onclick='centerMapInfo("+data[i]+");return false;'>"+data[i].dev_name+"<span class='"+span_class+"'>"+data[i].fleet_name+"</span></li>")
    ...
});
```

This data is a JSON (I don't know if it's important). What I don't understand is why when I send it alone `centerMapInfo(data[i])` it works perfectly, but when I send it when I click on my link, `onclick='centerMapInfo("+data[i]+");` it crashes.

The error is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Then, I understand I'm sending it wrong because I'm mistaking how to write it (probably is a silly thing but I can't see it). Can somebdoy help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you need to pass in the entire object consider serialising it with JSON.stringify. At a glance it looks like that will be resolving to `centerMapInfo([object Object])`

Comment: Why you don't just pass `i` and let the function get the contents?

Answer (score 0):

Let `data` be a global and access it inside the function using the index only. Also instead of using `onclick`, bind an event handler to the element.

```
var globalData;

function centerMapInfo(index){
  console.log(globalData[index]);
}

$("body").on("click", "li.fleet", function(ev) {
  centerMapInfo(parseInt(ev.target.dataSet.index));
  ev.preventDefault();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  console.log('START');
  globalData = data;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ....
    centerMapInfo(i)
    $("#"+id_list).append(
      `<li class='${li_class} list-group-item-warning font-weight-bold fleet' 
           data-index='${i}'>
         ${data[i].dev_name}
         <span class='${span_class}'>
           ${data[i].fleet_name}
         </span>
      </li>`);
      ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
onclick='centerMapInfo(\””+data[i]+"\”);
```

Comment: Can you print the data object?

Comment: `{data_id: 2379372, gateway: "Roda", data_timestamp: "2020-02-04T16:12:44.900Z", rssi: -120, snr: -9, …}`

Comment: But dev_nane and fleet_name are defined? I don’t see them.

Comment: Yes, this json has much more params, and two of they are `dev_name` and `fleet_name`